# View pushed down after status bar hides?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios9, uistatusbar

I have a `UIViewController` with no status bar, and it launches a second `UIViewController` that has a status bar.

If the extended status bar is active, both views show correctly, but when I exit the second view and go back to the first, I see a 20pt black bar at the top and the whole view is pushed down, obscuring the bottom.

I tried resetting the frame to origin 0,0 in `viewDidAppear` but it has no effect.

Why is the view pushed down and how can I fix it?

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
   return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, self.height);
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void)openShare {
  Share *share = [[Share alloc] init];
  UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:share];

  nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
  [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

top of the view before `openShare` is called:

[image]

top of the view after `Share` is presented and dismissed:

[image]

Comment: Did you configure the plist for viewcontroller based status bar apearence??And the views frame has nothing to do with the black view.Changing the window frame might work but i don't think its a good idea

Comment: Yes I set `<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key<true/>`

Comment: How can I change the window frame? `window` doesn't seem to exist in view controller

Comment: UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window

Comment: ok I tried that but nothing changed

Comment: Did you ever find out what caused this? I'm having the same issue and can't seem to find a way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had the exact same problem in my app.

I made two things that solve the problem.

1. I set the `Top Space to: Top Layout Guide` constraint with a constant of 20 (same as status bar height) on my navigationBar

   [image: Constaint]
2. I added this in the controllers that have the issue (`[self.view layoutSubviews]`)

   ```
   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];

       [self.view layoutSubviews];
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't have a navbar. I tried the second solution but it had no effect

Comment: Navigationbar was an exemple. Use this solution with any controls

Comment: ok I'm not using a storyboard, what's the code equivalent of #1?